# TYPO3: tx_news get sys_category sys_categories for custom title in BE list

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, extbase, tx-news

I extended tx_news to hold a number of courses. there are courses that treat the same subject matter for different arguments (which I select as sys_categories). This means that their title is identical, now I'm trying to make the list better for the editor by including the selected category in the list...

Imply a custom title in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['ctrl']['label_userFunc'] = 'Vendor\\NewsExt\\Userfuncs\\Tca->customTitle';
```

The userfunction so far `Classes/Userfuncs/Tca.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\NewsExt\Userfuncs;

use GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News;

/**
 * Class Tca
 */
class Tca
{
    /**
     * Loads a custom title for the news list view
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function customTitle(
        &$parameters,
        $parentObject
    ){
        $record = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getRecord($parameters['table'], $parameters['row']['uid']);
        $newTitle = $record['title'];
        if($record['is_course']){
            $newTitle .= ' (' . $record['categories'] . ')' ;
        }
        $parameters['title'] = $newTitle;
    }
}
```

which obviously gives the number of selected categories ... I did not include any of my attempts because they lead to nothing ...

Comment: What `$record['is_course']` is showing when you debug it? Has it the expected value?

Comment: @David , it does, it's a binary field that signs a news as being a course so that I can narrow down the setup for courses only, and indeed in my list only 'courses' show (1) added to the title

Comment: So the issue is solved?

Comment: @David absolutely not ... instead of the number of categories as given by `$record['categories']` i need to display the sys_categories titles !! the code I wrote so far is fully functional, that was not the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an mm query to resolve the assigned category title:

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\NewsExt\Userfuncs;

  use GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News;

  /**
   * Class Tca
   */
  class Tca
  {
    /**
     * Loads a custom title for the news list view
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function customTitle(&$parameters, $parentObject)
    {
      # fetch all categories assigned to this news
      $result = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECT_mm_query(
        'sys_category.uid, sys_category.title',
        'sys_category',
        'sys_category_record_mm',
        $parameters['table'],
        'AND sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = "' . $parameters['table'] . '" ' .
        'AND sys_category_record_mm.fieldname = "categories" ' .
        'AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = ' . $parameters['row']['uid']
      );

      # walk the categories an get the title of them
      $categoriesLabels = [];
      foreach ($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $category) {
        $categoriesLabels[] = $category['title'];
      }

      # if at least one category put them into the title
      if (!empty(array_filter($categoriesLabels))) {
        $record = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getRecord($parameters['table'], $parameters['row']['uid']);
        $parameters['title'] = $record['title'] . ' ('. implode(', ', $categoriesLabels) .')';
      }
    }
  }
```

**Note:** This code is was tested in TYPO3 8.7.12

Comment: `# walk the categories an get the title of them` produces an error: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: works ! if nobody offers a Solution using code from the news extension itself ... if that where possible, I'm going to accept your answer ... give it a day or two !

Comment: In this content you dont have an connection to the news extension. You could try to initialize the `NewsRepository` via the `ObjectManager` and get so the wanted news. But then you get all other properties of the model, too. So for this purpose its an little overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you've to make a custom database-query at best in an own repository where you request each applying category to get the title.

It's possible that you can use the Repository of tx_news for avoiding redundant code but surely you've to include some code / function that is instantiating the request - where ever the request is addressed to.